# How to create a new column based on a partial string of another column in tidyverse

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

I have read a lot of Stack Overflow articles on this topic, but I think it comes to my failure to understand strings (which I intend to rectify in the near future) as to why they aren't helpful in my case.

Say I have a data frame with a column called `names` that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 1
   names            
   <chr>           
 1 FAST.1_MOON_CAT 
 2 FAST.2_MOON_CAT 
 3 FAST.3_MOON_CAT 
 4 FAST.4_MOON_CAT 
 5 FAST.5_MOON_CAT 
 6 FAST.6_MOON_CAT 
 7 FAST.7_MOON_CAT 
 8 FAST.8_MOON_CAT 
 9 FAST.9_MOON_CAT 
10 FAST.10_MOON_CAT
```

I want to extract the number after the `.` and before the `_`, so essentially just the integer, and put that in a column called `group`:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
  names            group
   <chr>            <chr>
 1 FAST.1_MOON_CAT  1    
 2 FAST.2_MOON_CAT  2    
 3 FAST.3_MOON_CAT  3    
 4 FAST.4_MOON_CAT  4    
 5 FAST.5_MOON_CAT  5    
 6 FAST.6_MOON_CAT  6    
 7 FAST.7_MOON_CAT  7    
 8 FAST.8_MOON_CAT  8    
 9 FAST.9_MOON_CAT  9    
10 FAST.10_MOON_CAT 10
```

The problem is the numbers could be anything. They could be `1`, they could be `48`, they could be `1000089` (though they would likely never exceed 4 digits). How do I extract the numbers without knowing how many digits there will be?

Comment: You could do `df$group <- stringr::str_extract(df$names, "\\d+")` or `df$group <- gsub("\\D+", "", df$names)`

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much!